# how to change cell value of custom dynamic column in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

i added custom column to ag-grid like this

```
 this.columnDefs.push( {headerName: "Action Status", cellStyle:{"text-align":"center"}});
```

how to change a cell value of this column in runtime ?

i tried this solution but not work

```
this.gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(function (rowNode:RowNode) {
   rowNode.columnController.originalColumns[1].colDef.headerCellTemplate="test"

});

      this.gridOptions.api.softRefreshView();
        this.gridOptions.api.refreshView();
```

Answer (score 4):

the answer

- first put the field name like this

> ```
>  this.columnDefs.push(
>             {headerName: "Action Status",field:"actionStatus", cellStyle:{"text-align":"center"} })
> ```

-set new value like this

```
this.gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(function (rowNode:RowNode) {

            rowNode.setDataValue("actionStatus","the new value") ... ... ...
```